# Form based Authentication- Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am testing an API endpoint for which there is a form based authentication(for additional security). Can someone suggest how to handle form based authentication in Jmeter. I tried with HTTP Authorization Manage, still my request is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to submit a [HTML Form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) by sending a [HTTP POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

Given you provide correct credentials you should be authorized for further actions.

In some cases you will need to perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) as you might have to provide a dynamic parameter (or several) along with the credentials as your application can use these parameters for i.e. [CSRF protection](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md) or for other reasons so make sure to carefully inspect the request sent by the real browser (you can capture the original request using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)) and if there are any dynamic parameters - you should extract them from the previous response using a suitable [JMeter Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)

Once you successfully log in it should be enough to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to maintain the user session.